# javamail receiving problems

Tags: java, blob, jakarta-mail, multipart

I'm having a big problem. I have to interpret the meetings sent to a specific mail account. The problem is that I cant interpret them alone, with attachs, but if the meeting is forwarded my code crash.

```
            Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
            for (int x = 0; x < multipart.getCount(); x++)
            {
                BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(x);
                String[] nameHeader = bodyPart.getHeader("Content-Disposition");
                String disposition = bodyPart.getDisposition();
                if (bodyPart.isMimeType("multipart/alternative") || bodyPart.isMimeType("multipart/MIXED")  ){
                    Multipart multipart2 = (Multipart) bodyPart.getContent();
                    for (int y = 0; y < multipart2.getCount(); y++){
                        BodyPart bodyPart2 = multipart2.getBodyPart(y);
                        if (bodyPart2.isMimeType("text/calendar"))
                        {
                            partCalendar = bodyPart2;
                        }else if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/html") || bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain"))
                        {
                            body += bodyPart.getContent().toString();
                        }
                    }   
                }
                else if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/calendar"))
                {
                        if (nameHeader != null && !nameHeader[0].isEmpty()) 
                        {
                            partCalendar = bodyPart;
                            DataHandler handler = bodyPart.getDataHandler();
                            //here enters the forwarded
                        }
                        else{
                            partCalendar = bodyPart;
                        }
                } else if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/html") || bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain"))
                {
                    body += bodyPart.getContent().toString();
                } else if (disposition != null && (disposition.equals(BodyPart.ATTACHMENT)))
                {
                    System.out.println("Hay attach");
                }}
```

This is how I get the information of the calendar

```
Blob calendarContent = NonContextualLobCreator.INSTANCE.wrap(NonContextualLobCreator.INSTANCE
                    .createBlob(partCalendar.getInputStream(), partCalendar.getSize()));
```

It looks that:
- When the meeting has no attachs it's mimetype is "text/calendar" without Content-disposition header and without a file name.
- When the meeting has an attach in the same mail the type is "multipart/alternative" so I have to get the bodyparts of that body part

This two are working, but the problem is when the meeting is forwarded:

-When te meeting is forwarded the mimtetype of the mail is "text/calendar" and the "Content-Disposition" has the name of the file, but I cant extract the content like the two others because i cant generate the Blob.

Content-type of the 3rd point (TEXT/CALENDAR; charset=UTF-8; method=REQUEST; name=invite.ics)
Content-type of the 1st point (TEXT/CALENDAR; charset=UTF-8; method=REQUEST)

Sorry for my english I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "code crash"?  Are you getting an exception?  Which exception?  Which line of your program causes the exception?  Is it possible that some method you're calling is returning null, and you're assuming it will never return null?

Comment: yes, it seems that partCalendar.getInputStream() doesn't give the content of the calendar.. i dont know why..

Comment: What does "doesn't give the content" mean?  You get null?  An empty stream?  A stream with data, but not the data you expect?

Comment: The content is not the data that I expect

Comment: What **was** the data?

Comment: The content of the calendar meeting..

Comment: I don't understand.  First you say it "doesn't give the content of the calendar", then you say it instead gives "the content of the calendar meeting".  What's the difference?  I really need a lot more details to help you debug this.

Comment: I'm Sorry. I thought that you were asking about the data i need.The data I expect is the calendar. The data i'm receiving doesnt have the calendar. It seems that the calendar is interpret as attach.